# Assign value to elements of a list in Python (Yahtzee game)

Tags: python

I am trying to build a Yahtzee game in  Python.

The code works - but I have two fundamental problems:

1. Can't seem to make a hierarchy of scores, e.g.: Yahtzee is the best, then comes three of a kind, two pairs etc..
2. Can't seem to make 6's matter more than 5's and so forth..

My program looks like this:

```
import random

dice_sp1 = [0, 0, 0, 0]
dice_sp2 = [0, 0, 0, 0]

for x in range (4):
        dice_sp1[x] = random.randint(1,6)
        dice_sp2[x] = random.randint(1,6)

dice_sp1.sort()
dice_sp2.sort()

def roll():
  print("Player 1, you rolled", dice_sp1)
  print("Player 2, you rolled", dice_sp2)

roll()

def score_Board(user = dice_sp1, player = "Player 1"):
  if dice_sp1[0] == dice_sp1[3]:
    print("Gratz" + player +" - you have Yahtzee!")
  elif (user[0] == user[2]) or (dice_sp1[1] == dice_sp1[3]):
    print(player + " you have three of a kind")
  elif (user[0] == user[1]) and (user[2] == user[3]):
   print(player + " you have two pair")
  elif (user[0] == user[1]) or (user[1] == user[2]) or (user[2] == user[3]):
   print(player + " you have one pair",)
  else:
    print(player + " No match - highest value is", max(user)) 


score_Board()
score_Board(dice_sp2, "Player 2")

def win():
  if dice_sp1[x] > dice_sp2[x]:
    print("Player 1 wins")
  elif dice_sp1[x] < dice_sp2[x]:
    print("Player 2 wins")
  else:
    print("draw")


win()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use your `score_Board` function to set each players result to a variable then compare the results in your win function.

```
def score_Board():
    if dice_sp1[0] == dice_sp1[3]:
         print("Gratz" + player +" - you have Yahtzee!")
         return 'Yahtzee'
    elif (user[0] == user[2]) or (dice_sp1[1] == dice_sp1[3]):
         print(player + " you have three of a kind")
         return 'three of a kind'
    elif (user[0] == user[1]) and (user[2] == user[3]):
         print(player + " you have two pair")
         return 'two pair'
    elif (user[0] == user[1]) or (user[1] == user[2]) or (user[2] == user[3]):
         print(player + " you have one pair",)
         return 'one pair'
    else:
         print(player + " No match - highest value is", max(user))
         return max(user)

sp1 = score_Board()
sp2 = score_Board(dice_sp2, "Player 2")

...

win(sp1, sp2)
```

Comment: Thanks @Wytamma! for the qucik response I am not sure I understand what you mean? Can you come a little closer with an example maybe?

Comment: I have put in the return() function.

Comment: `return` is a statement in python so you don't need the (). You will have to modify your win() function to compare the results of the 2 players. Try starting with 
def win(sp1, sp2):
  print(sp1, sp2)